# mysql insert and select all at once

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL so bear with me please. I have set up a member table and a session table. When insert a new record in member table, session table will grab the assigned new record ID from member table and automatically insert into session table. Is this possible?

so the order will be something like:
insert new record(member table) -> fetch id(member table) -> insert new record(session table)

-I have already set up a foreign key in session table, but I don't know what to do
-Im using php, if this matter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easily you can use LAST_INSERT_ID();

your query can be like this:

```
    INSERT INTO members (id, name)
    VALUES('', 'test');
    INSERT INTO sessions (member_id, description) 
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'some description');
```

in this case id is set auto increment.
at the moment you insert your data into member table by using (LAST_INSERT_ID) the last inserted id will store in session table.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution :)